# Как сохранить результат функции pprint в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую следующий код:

```
from pprint import pprint

a = {'fields' : [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]}    
b = {'items' : [['a', 's', 'd', 'f'], ['s', 'a', 'd', 'f'], ['d', 's' ,'f', 'a']]}     
a_and_b = [dict(zip(a['fields'], x)) for x in b['items']]    
pprint (a_and_b, width=1)
```

На выходе получаю:

```
[{1: 'a',
  2: 's',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'f'},
 {1: 's',
  2: 'a',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'f'},
 {1: 'd',
  2: 's',
  3: 'f',
  4: 'a'}]
```

Все классно и здорово, но как мне сохранить результат функции pprint в переменную? (в файл очень не хотелось бы)

Если сделать следующее:

```
q = pprint(a_and_b, width=1)
```

функция отрабатывает и выводит данные в консоль (хотя по сути мне вывод в консоль не требуется, интересует только приведение результата в читаемый вид), но в дальнейшем
q = None

Comment: По мне, pprint выводит некрасиво, в отличии от форматирования как json с отступом в 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо функции `pprint` используйте `pformat`:

```
from pprint import pformat

...

q = pformat(a_and_b, width=1)
print(q)
```

---

Я бы предложил еще вариант отобразить в `json`:

```
import json

...

print(json.dumps(a_and_b, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```